# what is the CDF of $f(x)=\frac{3x^2}{2}$?

Tags: probability, density-function

This is probably a dumb question but I just want to make sure. The pdf is $f(x)=\frac{3x^2}{2}$ if $-1 \leq 0 \leq 1$. The CDF is $F(x)=\frac{x^3}{2}$ but with what bounds? sorry if this is an easy and obvious answer.

Comment: Use the fact that a CDF can only take values in $[0,1]$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the CDF isn't quite equal to $\frac{x^3}{2}$. Instead,
$$ F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^xf(t)\;dt $$
This integral is equal to zero if $x<-1$, is equal to
$$ \int_{-1}^x\frac{3t^2}{2}\;dt=\frac{x^3}{2}+\frac{1}{2} $$
if $-1\leq x\leq 1$, and is equal to $1$ if $x>1$.